# Delete a changeset from the server

Tags: mercurial

I've accidentally committed some binary files that have no place in the repository. Normally I would just use `hg rollback`, but because I'm a very quick programmer I've also pushed them to the server before realizing what I have done. Is there any way to delete this last commit from history entirely and drop it from the server's tree as well?

I don't mind deleting these files and making another commit, but I don't want to drag these files everywhere from now on (i. e. I don't want to have them in the history when I make a fresh `clone`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to log into the server and use `hg strip` to delete the offending changesets.  This cannot be done remotely via `hg push` because pushing is an append-only operation.  If anyone else has pulled those changesets, they will need to execute the same strip command.  You should also ensure the changesets do not appear in your own repository.

You will also need to enable the [strip extension](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StripExtension) on the server in order to use the strip command.

If you're on Bitbucket, the repository settings page has a "strip changesets" option which does much the same thing.

Once [changeset evolution](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChangesetEvolution) fully stabilizes, this process will become significantly simpler, but only if the server is non-publishing.

Comment: I am using Bitbucket! Thanks a lot. I had no idea `strip` can be executed on the server side.